# Using a virtual host result in internal error

Tags: environments, apache

I'm trying to setup a virtual host to access my craft project through ontherocks.dev, without any success yet.

- **www.ontherocks.dev** : correct response
- **www.ontherocks.dev/admin** : Apache 404
- **www.ontherocks.dev/index.php/admin** : redirected to *www.ontherocks.dev/admin/install* with an Apache 404

I didnt "install" craft yet, which explains the redirect. Here are my config files for the virtual host :

### httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ontherocks.dev
  DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\y-lynx"
  ServerAlias www.ontherocks.dev
 DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

### hosts file in system32/drivers/etc

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       ontherocks.dev
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try setting `ServerAlias` to `ontherocks.dev` (minus the www) and access the site using `ontherocks.dev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `.htaccess` file included with Craft is not being read or you didn't rename it (should be `.htaccess` with the period at the beginning).

That's why `/index.php/admin` is working but `/admin/` is not.

One other possibility is Apache is setup to ignore .htaccess files. If that's the case, add this to your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

```
<Directory "C:\wamp\www\y-lynx">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

(If you already have a `<Directory "C:\wamp\www\y-lynx">` block, just add in `AllowOverride All` somewhere inside.)

Comment: Thanks mate, that was part of the problem :). The real one was that I'm dumb and forgot to check if mod_rewrite was on, which wasn't. Anyway thanks !